# How to call specific fields from models.py in the views.py in Django

Tags: python, django, typeerror

I want to add a message after a successful form submission, with parts of the message involving parameter values from the apps model.

I have tried using method as follows:

views.py:

```
class ApplyView(FormView):
template_name = 'vouchers/apply.html'
model = Voucher
form_class = VoucherApplyForm


def form_valid(self, form):
    self.code = form.cleaned_data['code']
    now = timezone.now()
    Voucher.objects.filter(code__iexact=self.code,
                           valid_from__lte=now,
                           valid_to__gte=now,
                           usage_limit=3,
                           active=True)

    form.apply_voucher()
    return super(ApplyView, self).form_valid(form)

def get_success_url(self, voucher_id):
    voucher = Voucher.objects.filter(pk=voucher_id)

    discount_value = voucher.value
    discount_type = voucher.get_type_display


    messages.add_message(self.request, messages.INFO,
                         "Congratulations! You've successfully redeemed %s"
                         " %s off the selected item(s)." % (
                             discount_value,
                             discount_type,
                         ))
    return reverse('vouchers:apply', kwargs={'voucher_id': self.kwargs['voucher_id']})
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [

path('<int:pk>/', views.VoucherDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
path('<int:voucher_id>/apply/', views.ApplyView.as_view(), name='apply'),

]
```

However, I received a TypeError:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
TypeError: get_success_url() missing 1 required positional argument: 'voucher_id'
```

Your help is much appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_success_url` is called within the parent class of your view. It by definition doesn't have any arguments other than `self`. If you need to define other arguments on that method then you need to update the callers to supply them. This means you would need to override some other methods.

The other option and I suspect the one you'd prefer to use is to get the `voucher_id` from the kwargs of the view instance. This can be done with `self.kwargs['voucher_id']`

```
def get_success_url(self):
    voucher = Voucher.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['voucher_id'])
    ...
```